# Can someone give me some insight on how to simplify this problem?

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin, homework, superposition

It is hard for me to understand how to start solving this problem. Should I start using the superposition theorem? Can it be simplified before?

[image: Image of the question text and schematic]

Comment: Yes, it can be radically simplified but I do wish the schematic posted was more consistent in their use of symbols. That prevents me leaving an answer.

Comment: @Andyaka  current sources are represented by the double coil symbol (with a sinusoid when variable and an arrow when constant). DC voltage sources are represented by circles with an arrow inside, while AC voltage sources are represented by circles with a sinusoid inside. It's perfectly consistent.

Comment: @SredniVashtar A single circle with an arrow inside is the well-accepted symbol for a DC *current* source for much of the world. Calling it "perfectly consistent" is a stretch -- even if it's consistent with *some* (unspecified) standard and/or by referencing textual elements, it's not particularly usable because of the inconsistency with the commonly accepted standard. If anything, the set of symbols provided by the built-in circuit editor should be used as it's a *de facto* standard that users here are used to seeing.

Comment: Sorry, this is just one of the exercises that I took from previous exams at my course. I am not very aware of the symbolic conventions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Superposition is a good thing to try any time you have multiple sources. In this case, it's mandatory because you have both AC and DC sources. So your overall strategy should be to solve the circuit separately at AC and DC.

If you try drawing the AC and DC equivalent circuits, you'll see what simplifications can be made. Pay careful attention to what happens to the sources in each situation.

EDIT: You can consider each source separately if you'd like. AC or DC equivalent means the circuit with only the AC sources or only the DC sources active. For DC, this means killing \$I_1\$ and \$E_1\$ and replacing the inductor and capacitor with their DC equivalents. For AC, it means killing \$I_2\$ and \$E_2\$. This is useful for looking at the role of inductors and capacitors. For example, the inductor has no effect on the circuit in either case and can be removed.

Remember, your goal is to find the voltage between the two open terminals on the right. With only \$I_1\$ active, you can see that there are only resistors between the two terminals:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZneRb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Kirchhoff's Current Law says that none of \$I_1\$'s current leaves the loop on the left. So \$I_1\$ has no effect on the voltage between the terminals on the right. That voltage is zero. So \$I_1\$ has no effect (it does not contribute to the Thevenin voltage), which means you can remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am not very sure what it mean to draw the ac and dc equivalent circuits? Would you clarify please? 
I have tried the superposition method by considering each of the sources separately and 'canceling' the others. Is that what you mean? 
Also, when considering I1, I open I2 and short E1 and E2. The result is that there is a zero resistance path from I1 to the lower end on the right. What happens in this case then?

Comment: @FlávioMaia I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!